# JOIN with 2 Tables (Voting) Mysql, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, voting

Hello I have 3 Tables but i need only help with 2 Tables.

The first Table is `champions`. In this Table are over 100 names.

The second Table is `champion_names` there are nicknames for the first Table.

The third Table is `champion_names_vote`. There are the votes for the nicknames. Thumb up if I like any nickname or thumb down.

On my website I have a site where I can see a list full of Names `(Table 1)`. There are 2 columns. In the first is the normal name `(Table 1)` in the second the nickname `(Table 2)`. Now I want to show the best nickname in column 2. Actually it's random but I only want to show the best nickname.

I can show all Names that's not the problem. But if I want to show only the best nicknames I don't know how.

```
Table 2: id(AI), champ_id(this is the id for Table 1), sender_id, name

Table 3: id(AI), userid, name_id(Table 2 ID), like_dislike
```

like_dislike = 1 is like, -1 is dislike and 0 is nothing.

Example:

```
Table 2: 50, 2, 4, Test
Table 3: 1, 3, 50, 1,
```

I liked the name of `Table 2`. So the `name_id` in `Table 3` is the `id` of `Table 2`

So how can I do this with JOIN?
Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick.

Idea is to Analyse your votes per nickname first. Then select the Maximum vote-score by `HAVING`:

```
SELECT voteResult.name, vote as winnerVoteScore
FROM(
    select a.name_id, b.name,
    sum(IF(a.like_dislike = 1, 1, IF(a.like_dislike = 2, -1, 0 ))) as vote
    FROM champion_names_vote as a JOIN champion_names as b 
    ON a.name_id = b.ID
    GROUP BY 1
) as voteResult
GROUP BY 1 
HAVING vote = max(vote)
```